# Accessing Postgres named CHECK CONSTRAINTS from jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq, check-constraints

I have defined a named check constraint in Postgres 10:

```
  constraint date_start_smaller_than_date_end check (date_start < date_end)
```

I'm running the jOOQ 3.11.4 generator, but I cannot find any class that was generated with that name. It is not defined in `Keys`, even though it mentions in the comments that

```
/**
 * A class modelling foreign key relationships and constraints of tables of 
 * the <code>public</code> schema.
 */
```

In [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7608) it is mentioned, that one cannot turn off check constraint generation.

Anybody know what classes are generated, and where they are generated to?

Comment: It would be great to learn about your requirements and ideas for possible new features on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user)

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.11, the jOOQ code generator does support reading check constraint meta data through the jOOQ-meta module, but it does not yet generate any code from it (see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7639). There is still a lot of work to do around check constraints, apart from supporting them in DDL statements.